# AWS KMS throws exception on encrypt

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

Created a method to encrypt data using AWS KMS. It was working for a while then I'm experiencing the following exception. Even tried creating a new key but no luck! Not sure if it is something to do with the account limit!

Method call:

```
String keyArn = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:account-id:key/key-id"; 
ByteBuffer record = ByteBuffer.wrap("Testing Encryption".getBytes("UTF-8"));                                          
DataEncryptor.encrypt(record, keyArn);
```

Method:

```
public static ByteBuffer encrypt(ByteBuffer record, String keyArn) {
    kms = new AWSKMSClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials()).withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1);
    EncryptRequest req = new EncryptRequest().withKeyId(keyArn).withPlaintext(record);
    EncryptResult encrypt = kms.encrypt(req);
    return encrypt.getCiphertextBlob();
}
```

this is not

```
com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.AWSKMSException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'plaintext' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1 (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: a9cb4684-55f1-11e7-8e35-b1ca13e97a3e)

at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.doInvoke(AWSKMSClient.java:2607)
at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:2583)
at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.encrypt(AWSKMSClient.java:1256)
at com.amazon.kinesis.kafka.encryption.RecordEncryptor.encrypt(RecordEncryptor.java:41)
at com.amazon.kinesis.kafka.encryption.RecordEncryptorTest.decrypt_shouldDecryptAGivenEncryptedRecord(RecordEncryptorTest.java:37)
```

Comment: The error *seems* to be complaning that `record` is zero-length.

Comment: I dont think so. My input is "ABCDEF"

Comment: Is this solved? If yes, how did you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is empty, check whether you are referencing the correct file.
I had same error but I was referencing it to the wrong file. so my content was in ExampleSecret and I was referring ExampleSecret.txt in the command.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and i solved it after checking KMS customer key that need to link with this specific Lambda function.
Go to KMS, then Customer managed keys, for the key i created for this Lambda function. checking its Key users is contains this Lambda or not.